# Remove horizontal line <hr> when screen width <767

Tags: css

How can you hide the horizontal line tag `<hr>` when the screen width is smaller than `767px`?

How can this be done using css only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
@media(max-width:767px) {
  hr {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<hr />
```

More info on [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Answer (score 4):

You can use CSS to do that, it will take the device width in pixels and check if it's true.

```
@media (max-width:767px) { hr { visibility: none; } //This will make the hr hidden if the screen size is under 767px
```

Or you can just use JavaScript to check the width and see if you should deliver the hr to the page.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not tagged, but the Javascript would be as follows:

HTML:

```
<hr id="rule" />
```

JS:

```
if(window.innerWidth < 767){
   document.getElementById("rule").style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
else{
   document.getElementById("rule").style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    hr{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As inline css:

```
    <style media="screen">

  
  hr{
   
    border-style: none;

  }

</style>
```

As inside hr tag:

```
<hr style = "border-style: none">
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).